# How to print without a comma?

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke a method to print "R, a, b, b, i, t". My method should print nothing if the empty string ("") is passed.

```
public static void printLetters(String a) {
    if (a == "")
        System.out.println(a);
    else
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - 1; i++) {
            char rabb = (a.charAt(i));
            System.out.print(rabb + ",");

            if (i != a.length() - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
}
```

Problem now is  I am printing "r,a,b,b,it", and I am not sure why. It seems like `if(i!=a.length()-1){` is not working to eliminate the last comma.

Comment: Please fix your whitespace.

Comment: Right now you only print an extra space after the last comma. You cannot "undo" a print command once it is completed. You need to change your code so that you completely avoid printing the last comma at all.

Answer (score 3):

First, never use `==` for string comparison, use `.equals`:

```
if ("".equals(a))
```

In your for loop, extract the character and print it only.  Then, if you detect that you're not at the end of the string, then print a comma and a space.

```
char rabb = (a.charAt(i));
System.out.print(rabb);

if (i != a.length() - 1) {
     System.out.print(", ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
             char rabb = (a.charAt(i));
             if(i==a.lenght()-1){
             System.out.print(rabb + ",");
             }
             else 
             System.out.print(rabb);
```

Also, your string comparision is wrong. use equals method to compare strings.

```
if ("".equals(a))
```

you can also use `String.isEmpty()` to check if a string is empty

```
 if (a.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier is to delete the last character, since the coma is the last character, just delete it based on the position using the String class methods

```
String myString = "a,b,c,d,"

String newString = myString.subString(0,myString.length()-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String comma(String a) {
    if (a.length() == 0)
        return "";
    char[] c = new char[a.length()+a.length()-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length()*2-2; i+=2) {
        c[i] = a.charAt(i/2);
        c[i+1] = ',';
    }
    c[c.length-1] = a.charAt(a.length()-1);
    return new String(c);
}
```